# Does XElement internally store an object implementing IEnumerable<A> as a string content ( thus as XText )?

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml

How does in the following example `XElement` internally store an object implementing `IEnumerable<A>`? Is `ToString` called on each of **A** type objects stored in this collection and the resulting value is treated as a string content ( as a`XText`) and is thus appended to "someString" value, or ...?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A[]  = new A[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            a[i] = new A();

        XElement element = new XElement("XMLElement", "someString", a);
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}

class A { }
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943882.aspx for an explanation what you can pass in as contents of `XDocuments` and `XElements` with the constructors and methods like Add.
For your `A` instances you are right that ToString() is called and that each result of that called is appended to form the Value of a single `XText` child node of the "XMLElement" `XElement` you create.

Comment: I assume if IEnumerable<T> is passed as an argument to XElement constructor, and if T is not of type or doesn't derive from XAttribute or Xnode, then resulting value is always treated as a XText child node?

Comment: Well you can do stuff like `List<object> example = new List<object>() { DateTime.Now, decimal.MaxValue, "Kibology", new XComment("This is a comment"), int.MinValue, new XElement("foo", "bar"), new XAttribute("att", "value") }; XElement el = new XElement("element", example);` where `T` is simply `object` and then you will get several child nodes. So IEnumerable<T> is simply enumerated and then each item is treated as described on MSDN.

Comment: I worded my question awkwardly. What I should ask is whether resulting value of instance objects held by IEnumerable<T>, which are not of type or don't derive from XAttribute or XNode, is always treated as a XText child node?

Comment: I wouldn't say "treated as XText child node" as there is a difference, when you do e.g. `new XElement("foo", new List<object>() { new XText("Test 1."), new XText("Test 2."), new XText("Test 3.") }` then the resulting `foo` XElement node has three child nodes of type XText. On the other hand when you do e.g `new XElement("foo", new List<object>() { "Test 1.", "Test 2.", "Test 3." })` then the resulting `foo` element has simply one XText child node.